# How does typescript resolve the import of @angular/core/testing and how is angular core packaged?

Tags: javascript, angular, npm

For `import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';` I imagine that package.json's module attribute points to a file that exports `injectable`?
  For the format `@angular/core/testing` is there a testing folder within `@angular/core` that has another `package.json` with a module attribute pointing to the file containing the exports that the `testing` sub module exports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're onto something. Looking at the source code of the `@angular` module, you will indeed find a directory named `testing` which has it's own `package.json`.

Most `TypeScript` libraries use the `Barrel import / export` pattern to "beautify" your import paths.

*path/to/nested/files/injectable.ts*

```
export function Injectable() {
    ...
}
```

*dist/index.js* - The file that is exposed by `package.json` `main` property.

```
export { Injectable } from 'path/to/nested/files/injectable.ts'
```

This will allow you to

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
```

instead of

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core/path/to/nested/files/injectable.ts'
```

By separating modules, e.g. `core` from `testing`, you will benefit from `Tree-Shaking` as you only import stuff you need from a library instead of the whole package.